# What constitutes a "freelancing" problem on Freelancing SE?

Tags: discussion, site-topic, specific-question

We have a question asked by a new user, who is apparently an independent, self-employed programmer. The question, [EAN and UPC codes on Amazon](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/2396/ean-and-upc-codes-on-amazon), doesn't appear on the surface to be about freelancing itself. The best Stack Exchange sites have a very clearly defined definition of what is on topic, as well as what isn't on topic.

Where does this post fit into our goals of creating a resource of knowledge about freelancing?  Should this post be closed as off-topic?

Is it possible to edit the post to make it more about freelancing while still focusing on the problem?

Are there more users in our community with 500+ reputation who can help by voting to close?  There are already two close votes on the post; it needs 3 more.

Answer (score 3):

My instinct for flagging & claiming it is not about freelancing is it’s really more about business logistics. Which maybe someone who deals with freelancing might have to deal with. But if that door is held open, the next thing you know you will get tons of posts from freelancers on how to post to eBay or how to deal with PayPal.

Also, while I want to say there is another place for a question like that, the more I think about it the question is a straightforward question that can be posed directly to Amazon’s support team.

Answer (score 2):

I would vote to close if I could.

I think it is off topic because the answer would proably still be the same no matter if the person asking it were a freelancer or not.

I suspect that it isn't possible to save because of the above, unless there is a factor that makes it relevant that we don't know about.  That would be the responsibility of the OP.

I'm almost at 500 and keen to get involved here. When I get there I'll vote to close as necessary.

Comment: Thanks for weighing in, @Stacey. A couple of us are actually in [chat] right now; please join us if you have time.